# How to set home launcher in Android 7.0 Nougat and 8.0 Oreo

Tags: launcher, 7.0-nougat

I could not find the way to set/change the default launcher in Android N (Nexus 6P). I think it is not there. Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Changing the default launcher in Android O (as of 8.0 DP 1)**

- Go into the Settings app
- Go to "Apps & Notifications"
- Go to "Default apps"
- Press "Home app"

Alternatively, you can just search inside the settings app for "Home."

---

**Changing the default launcher in Android Nougat**

- Go into the Settings app
- Go to "Apps"
- Press the settings gear in the top-right (not the triple-dot)
- Scroll down and press "Home app"

Alternatively, you can just search inside the settings app for "Home."

**source:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpXBDnSIeiM

---

**Changing the default launcher in Android Marshmallow**

- Go into the Settings app
- Scroll down, and under the "Device" header you'll see "Home"
- Go into that and you'll be able to change your home launcher

---

**Changing the default launcher in Android Lollipop**

- Go into the Settings app
- Scroll down, and under the "Device" header you'll see "Home"
- Go into that and you'll be able to change your home launcher

---

**Changing the default launcher in Android KitKat**

- Go into the Settings app
- Scroll down, and under the "Device" header you'll see "Home"
- Go into that and you'll be able to change your home launcher

---

**Changing the default launcher in Android (pre-KitKat 4.4)**

You'll need a third-party app to change between home screens. One of the best ("Home Switch") is available here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.captainstu72.homeswitch

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I realized my answer was incorrect and I remade the answer with the actual information. Sorry about that :|. So look at my answer again, it's right now.

Comment: Thanks! I found that the search function in my settings does not work. But your answer helps.

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen Glad it helped!

Comment: I have never seen this "Home" option before.

Comment: @MarkYisri On the bottom of the  left image here: http://beebom.redkapmedia.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Android-N-vs-Android-Marshmallow-Settings.jpg . There you can see Marshmallow has a setting for home while Nougat does not.

Comment: No settings gear in latest version of Android Nougat for the answer below......... And searching for "home" in settings don't find the home app either. **Changing the default launcher in Android Nougat Go into the Settings appGo to "Apps"Press the settings gear in the top-right (not the triple-dot)Scroll down and press "Home app" Alternatively, you can just search inside the settings app for "Home."**

Comment: @Nickum that might already have switched to "Oreo style".

Answer (score 0):

Installing another launcher will cause Android to ask you which one you want when you hit the Home button.